# sample of kendo combo for relation table with id and value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, combobox, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i'm using kendo ui in my asp.net mvc 4 with razor views and encounter problem with kendo combo when the list load from an action via ajax with sending parameters to the server like the sample here:[HERE](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/combobox/overview)
 becuase the table has more then 2,000 rows.

when i load the edit page, the combo load and filter the data as expected, but the value of this field is - [object object].

i did declare the .DataTextField("ProffName") + .DataValueField("ID")

My ClientsController:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Clients clients = db.Clients.Find(id);
        if (clients == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewData["MyAgency"] = new SelectList(db.Agency, "ID", "AgentName", clients.AgencyId);
        ViewData["MyCategory1"] = new SelectList(db.CategoryTbl, "ID", "category", clients.CategoryId);

        List<SelectListItem> obj = new List<SelectListItem>();
        obj.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "male", Value = "1" });
        obj.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "female", Value = "2" });
        obj.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "choose", Value = "0" });
        ViewData["MyMin"] = obj;

        ViewBag.ProffID = new SelectList(db.ProfTBL, "ID", "ProffName", clients.ProffID);
        ViewBag.Metapel = new SelectList(db.Workers, "ID", "WorkerName", clients.Metapel);
        return View(clients);
    }
```

My ProffController:

```
public ActionResult ProffVM_Read(string text)
    {
        var Proff_Tbl = db.ProfTBL.Select(proff => new ProffVm { ID = proff.ID, ProffName = proff.ProffName });
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            Proff_Tbl = Proff_Tbl.Where(p => p.ProffName.Contains(text));
        }
        return Json(Proff_Tbl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and the Kendo combo:

```
@Html.Label("Proff")
                            @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.ProffID)
                              .Name("proffCbo")
                              .DataTextField("ProffName")
                              .DataValueField("ID")
                              .Events(e => e
                                    .Select("proffCbo_select")
                                    .Change("proffCbo_change")
                                )
                              .DataSource(source =>
                              {
                                  source.Read(read =>
                                  {
                                      read.Action("ProffVM_Read", "Proff")
                                               .Data("onAdditionalData");
                                  });
                              })
                            )
```

where am i wrong ???
i can change this combo to textbox but... i have to realize the magic.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using ComboBoxFor() then you need to make sure that the name of the combo box is the same as the model name-->.Name("ProffID")

Comment: i did as you say change the name to -->> .name("ProffId") and still get the field value [object object].

Comment: when i use the console to check the field value ==>$("#ProffId").val() i see that the value is "undefined".

Comment: It is probally that you are setting new ProffVm { ID = proff.ID...should that be ProffVm{ ProffID=...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but ProffId isn't The correct Field name in the Table DB. the field in the table is "ID". it's really help if you can give sample code of the "var Proff_Tbl = "... otherwise i get errors in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Change these two lines

```
var Proff_Tbl = db.ProfTBL.Select(proff => new ProffVm { ID = proff.ID, ProffName = proff.ProffName });

Proff_Tbl = Proff_Tbl.Where(p => p.ProffName.Contains(text));
```

to

```
var Proff_Tbl = db.ProfTBL.Select(proff => new ProffVm { ID = proff.ID, ProffName = proff.ProffName }).ToList();

Proff_Tbl = Proff_Tbl.Where(p => p.ProffName.Contains(text)).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, the problem was in the <script>. now the problem is saving the comboBox data. i see the values field is correct when i check the >> $("#ProffCbo").val()